# Passing Objects to Datagrid Command Argument

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I am new to ASP.Net DataGrid, I have a grid which has linkbutton on each row!!

On Itembound event I am getting the object which I am binding to the grid!! On button click, I need to send this object data to webservice!!

How do I get object on button click? CommandArgument is of string type, is there a way to pass object to CommandArgument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such way. This object basically exists only during the data binding period. And button click handling happens on a next request, so this object does not even exist anymore.

Your options are:

1. Best and most common. Pass the object id as an argument, and in the button click handler do a query (to the database, I presume) to get the object by id.
2. No so common and weird. Implement serialization and deserialization of your object. This way you can pass the whole serialized object string as an argument, and deserialize it on button click.